# Using Syphon Send Frames for MADMAPPER

Tags: processing, syphon

I am having trouble sending a sketch through Syphon to Madmapper.
The regular "send frames" sketch works, but when I try to incorporate the parameters to my sketch, the visualization doesn't show.

Please take a look at my code and let me know what am I doing wrong:

```java
   //Final Project
import codeanticode.syphon.*;


float rotation=0.1;
int num = 100, frms = 320;
float theta, time;
long rs; 
PGraphics canvas;
SyphonServer server;

//long: Use this datatype when you need a number to have a greater magnitude than can be 
//stored within an int.

void setup () {
  size(800, 800, P2D);
  canvas = createGraphics(800, 800, P2D);
  loop();
  server = new SyphonServer(this, "sublime");
};


void draw() {

  background(0);

canvas.beginDraw();
canvas.smooth();
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 255, 255, 20);
  rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);

  time = (frameCount % frms)/float(frms);
  paintQuads(); 
  theta += 2/TWO_PI/frms;
}



void paintQuads() {
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    fill(0);
    stroke(255);
    float r = random(-.5, .5);
    float sz = random(5, 15);
    resetMatrix(); //  Replaces the current matrix with the identity matrix. 
    // This effectively clears all transformation functions set before it.



    //multiply the quads

    //Translate
    //Specifies an amount to displace objects within the display window. 
    //The x parameter specifies left/right translation, the y parameter specifies up/down
    //translation, and the z parameter specifies translations toward/away from the screen. 
    //Using this function with the z parameter requires using P3D as a parameter in 
    //combination with size as shown in the above example. 


    translate(random(width), random(height));
    rotate(r);
    rotate(rotation); 

    //images

    noStroke();

    fill(255, 0, 0, 70);
    quad(38, 31, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);

    fill(255, 210, 0, 10);
    quad(width-9, height-9, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);

    fill(255, 0, 0, 30);
    ellipse(36, 36, 16, 16);

    fill(50, 46, 100, 20 );
    quad(46, 20, 14, 14, 46, 20, 14, 14);

    fill(50, 46, 100, 75);
    quad(50, 0, 12, 12, 50, 0, 12, 12);

    rotation=rotation+0.5;
  }
  canvas.endDraw();
  image(canvas, 0, 0);
  //send canvas to Syphon
  server.sendImage(canvas);
}
```

Thank you!
-k

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say your visualization doesn't show? Where doesn't it show? Do you get any exceptions or stack traces?

Comment: Hi Kevin, What I mean is, that the visualizations can't be seen in mad mapper. The sketch works, but I don't seem to be able to send the visuals to the areas I want. I can't see the images in Madmapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not using the PGraphics instance properly: some calls use it, some draw into the main sketch, but not the canvas PGraphics which is what you send to Syphon.

One quick fix is to call `server.sendScreen();` instead of `server.sendImage();`

This way what is see in Processing is what you see in MadMapper via Syphon:
[image: syphon mad mapper preview]

Alternatively you can fix your PGraphics calls:

```
//Final Project
import codeanticode.syphon.*;


float rotation=0.1;
int num = 100, frms = 320;
float theta, time;
long rs; 
PGraphics canvas;
SyphonServer server;

//long: Use this datatype when you need a number to have a greater magnitude than can be 
//stored within an int.

void setup () {
  size(800, 800, P2D);
  canvas = createGraphics(800, 800, P2D);
  loop();
  server = new SyphonServer(this, "sublime");
};


void draw() {

  background(0);

  canvas.beginDraw();
  canvas.smooth();
  canvas.background(0);
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 255, 255, 20);
  rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);

  time = (frameCount % frms)/float(frms);
  paintQuads(canvas); 
  theta += 2/TWO_PI/frms;

  canvas.endDraw();
  image(canvas,0,0);
  server.sendImage(canvas);
}



void paintQuads(PGraphics g) {
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    g.fill(0);
    g.stroke(255);
    float r = random(-.5, .5);
    float sz = random(5, 15);
    g.resetMatrix(); //  Replaces the current matrix with the identity matrix. 
    // This effectively clears all transformation functions set before it.



    //multiply the quads

    //Translate
    //Specifies an amount to displace objects within the display window. 
    //The x parameter specifies left/right translation, the y parameter specifies up/down
    //translation, and the z parameter specifies translations toward/away from the screen. 
    //Using this function with the z parameter requires using P3D as a parameter in 
    //combination with size as shown in the above example. 


    g.translate(random(width), random(height));
    g.rotate(r);
    g.rotate(rotation); 

    //images

    g.noStroke();

    g.fill(255, 0, 0, 70);
    g.quad(38, 31, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);

    g.fill(255, 210, 0, 10);
    g.quad(width-9, height-9, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);

    g.fill(255, 0, 0, 30);
    g.ellipse(36, 36, 16, 16);

    g.fill(50, 46, 100, 20 );
    g.quad(46, 20, 14, 14, 46, 20, 14, 14);

    g.fill(50, 46, 100, 75);
    g.quad(50, 0, 12, 12, 50, 0, 12, 12);

    rotation=rotation+0.5;
  }

  //  image(canvas, 0, 0);
  //send canvas to Syphon

  //  server.sendScreen();
}
```

Or if PGraphics is confusing to use for now, skip it altogether and send the screen:

```
//Final Project
import codeanticode.syphon.*;


float rotation=0.1;
int num = 100, frms = 320;
float theta, time;
long rs; 

SyphonServer server;

//long: Use this datatype when you need a number to have a greater magnitude than can be 
//stored within an int.

void setup () {
  size(800, 800, P2D);
  smooth();

  server = new SyphonServer(this, "sublime");
};


void draw() {

  background(0);

  noStroke();
  fill(255, 255, 255, 20);
  rect(mouseX, mouseY, 50, 50);

  time = (frameCount % frms)/float(frms);
  paintQuads(); 
  theta += 2/TWO_PI/frms;

  server.sendScreen();
}



void paintQuads() {
  for (int i=0; i<num; i++) {
    fill(0);
    stroke(255);
    float r = random(-.5, .5);
    float sz = random(5, 15);
    resetMatrix(); //  Replaces the current matrix with the identity matrix. 
    // This effectively clears all transformation functions set before it.



    //multiply the quads

    //Translate
    //Specifies an amount to displace objects within the display window. 
    //The x parameter specifies left/right translation, the y parameter specifies up/down
    //translation, and the z parameter specifies translations toward/away from the screen. 
    //Using this function with the z parameter requires using P3D as a parameter in 
    //combination with size as shown in the above example. 


    translate(random(width), random(height));
    rotate(r);
    rotate(rotation); 

    //images

    noStroke();

    fill(255, 0, 0, 70);
    quad(38, 31, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);

    fill(255, 210, 0, 10);
    quad(width-9, height-9, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);

    fill(255, 0, 0, 30);
    ellipse(36, 36, 16, 16);

    fill(50, 46, 100, 20 );
    quad(46, 20, 14, 14, 46, 20, 14, 14);

    fill(50, 46, 100, 75);
    quad(50, 0, 12, 12, 50, 0, 12, 12);

    rotation=rotation+0.5;
  }
}
```